# Codeigniter and pulling data from a model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am new to MVC and Codeigniter, and I have hit a hurdle, I have built a login system and now I want to pull data from a query in a model called `post`

Code for `post` model

```
class Post extends CI_MODEL {

    function stream($uid, $updated, $limit) {
        //SELECT * FROM vPAS_Posts_Users_Temp WHERE post_user_id =:id AND post_type !=4 AND post_updated >:updated AND post_updated <:now UNION SELECT u.* FROM vPAS_Posts_Users_Temp u JOIN PAS_Follow f ON f.folw_followed_user_id = u.post_dynamic_pid WHERE u.post_updated >:updated AND post_updated <:now AND (( f.folw_follower_user_id =:id AND f.folw_deleted = 0 ) OR ( u.post_passed_on_by = f.folw_follower_user_id OR u.post_passed_on_by =:id AND u.post_user_id !=:id AND u.post_type =4 )) ORDER BY post_posted_date DESC LIMIT :limit
        $now = microtime(true);
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                vPAS_Posts_Users_Temp 
            WHERE 
                post_user_id = ? 
                AND post_type !=4 
                AND post_updated > ?
                AND post_updated < ? 
            UNION 

            SELECT 
                u.* 
            FROM 
                vPAS_Posts_Users_Temp u 
            JOIN 
                PAS_Follow f 
                ON f.folw_followed_user_id = u.post_dynamic_pid 
                WHERE u.post_updated > ?
                AND post_updated < ? 
                AND (( f.folw_follower_user_id = ? AND f.folw_deleted = 0 ) 
                OR ( u.post_passed_on_by = f.folw_follower_user_id OR u.post_passed_on_by = ? AND u.post_user_id != ? AND u.post_type =4 )) 
            ORDER BY 
                post_posted_date DESC 
            LIMIT ?
        "; 

        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($uid, $updated, $now, $updated, $now, $uid, $uid, $uid, $limit));

        return $query->result_array();

    }

}
```

I would like to pull the results in to my `home` controller and work with them, I have written this in the `home` controller

```
function index() {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $data['first_name'] = $session_data['first_name'];
     $data['last_name'] = $session_data['last_name'];
     $this->load->library('gravatar');
     $data['gravatar'] = $this->gravatar->get_gravatar($session_data['username']);

     //Stream Data
     $updated = 0.0;
     $limit = 50;
     $uid = $session_data['id'];

     $this->load->model('post');
     $data['results'] = $this->post->stream($uid, $updated, $limit);

     $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
   } else {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
}
```

However when I do `echo json_encode($results);` in my view i just get `[]` returned, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: I think you should load model Post instead of post. same with when you're calling it.

Comment: where did you get that `db->query()` syntax? I have never seen it before.

Comment: @Phil I found it in the docs that came with my CI install is it wrong? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: no, I haven't used `CI` in a long time.. btw, for a point of troubleshooting... `this->db->last_query()` and put that in your db directly

Comment: maybe your sql code is incorrect, try to print $this->db->last_query() as Phil Suggested.
Also did you consider using Active Record ?

Comment: Thanks @Phil for your tip there, I realised that one of my session variables was incorrectly set and indeed once resolved the query works!

Comment: @JustinErswell As a side-note: change the `CI_MODEL` to `CI_Model` to prevent from  case-sensitive issue on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having taken @Phil advice I used `$this->db->last_query();` and found that one of the variables required for the query was not correct.

Being new to Codeigniter I hadn't seen all of the debug functions that come baked in. Thanks stack for helping me understand and resolve my issue.